# Issue with mapping functions: Error in expr_substitute(funs[[j]], quote(.), var_sym) : argument "var_sym" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, data-cleaning

So I have a list of data frames to which I'm trying to trim all the whitespace (using `stringr::str_squish)`) from each data frame.

I assume the best way to do this is to `mutate` each variable in each data frame, and mapping this to each data frame in the list.

The issue is that I keep getting this error:

```
Error in expr_substitute(funs[[j]], quote(.), var_sym) : 
  argument "var_sym" is missing, with no default
```

Here's what I'm doing (using the reproducible `dput` code from below):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

mydata %>%
  map(~mutate_all(., str_squish))
```

But this isn't working. Any ideas?

```
mydata <- list(structure(list(`Matchup
                                    Matchup` = c("Colorado\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        St. Louis\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  COL\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  STL", 
"Buffalo\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Edmonton\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  BUF\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  EDM", 
"NY Islanders\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Los Angeles\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  NYI\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  LAK"
), `Result
                                    Result` = c("COL 2,\n                                                    STL 4\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    COL 2,\n                                                    STL 4", 
"BUF 3,\n                                                    EDM 4\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    BUF 3,\n                                                    EDM 4", 
"NYI 0,\n                                                    LAK 1\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    NYI 0,\n                                                    LAK 1"
), c("Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
"Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
"Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER"
), `Networks
                            Networks` = c("G. Fuhr, \n                                            J. Campbell, \n                                            C. Pronger", 
"T. Marchant, \n                                            R. Smehlik, \n                                            A. Kovalenko", 
""), c("Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
"Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
"Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER"
), c(NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Matchup\n                                    Matchup", 
"Result\n                                    Result", "", "Networks\n                            Networks", 
"", ""), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    `Matchup
                                    Matchup` = c("NY Rangers\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Boston\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  NYR\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  BOS", 
    "Phoenix\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Hartford\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  PHX\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  HFD", 
    "Tampa Bay\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Pittsburgh\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  TBL\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  PIT", 
    "Ottawa\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Montréal\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  OTT\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  MTL", 
    "Detroit\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        New Jersey\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  DET\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  NJD", 
    "Florida\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Philadelphia\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  FLA\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  PHI", 
    "Chicago\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Washington\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  CHI\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  WSH", 
    "Anaheim\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Toronto\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  ANA\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  TOR", 
    "Colorado\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Dallas\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  COL\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  DAL", 
    "Calgary\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        Vancouver\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  CGY\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  VAN", 
    "NY Islanders\n                                      @\n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                                        San Jose\n                                      \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                \n                                  NYI\n                                \n                                    @\n                                \n                                  SJS"
    ), `Result
                                    Result` = c("NYR 4,\n                                                    BOS 4\n                                                      (OT)\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    NYR 4,\n                                                    BOS 4\n                                                      (OT)", 
    "PHX 0,\n                                                    HFD 1\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    PHX 0,\n                                                    HFD 1", 
    "TBL 4,\n                                                    PIT 3\n                                                      (OT)\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    TBL 4,\n                                                    PIT 3\n                                                      (OT)", 
    "OTT 3,\n                                                    MTL 3\n                                                      (OT)\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    OTT 3,\n                                                    MTL 3\n                                                      (OT)", 
    "DET 1,\n                                                    NJD 3\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    DET 1,\n                                                    NJD 3", 
    "FLA 3,\n                                                    PHI 1\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    FLA 3,\n                                                    PHI 1", 
    "CHI 5,\n                                                    WSH 2\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    CHI 5,\n                                                    WSH 2", 
    "ANA 1,\n                                                    TOR 4\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    ANA 1,\n                                                    TOR 4", 
    "COL 1,\n                                                    DAL 4\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    COL 1,\n                                                    DAL 4", 
    "CGY 1,\n                                                    VAN 3\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    CGY 1,\n                                                    VAN 3", 
    "NYI 2,\n                                                    SJS 2\n                                                      (OT)\n                                            \n                                  \n                                \n                                \n                                  \n                                            \n                                                    NYI 2,\n                                                    SJS 2\n                                                      (OT)"
    ), c("Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER"
    ), `Three Stars of the Game
                            Three Stars of the Game` = c("S. Heinze, \n                                            L. Robitaille, \n                                            J. Stumpel", 
    "S. Burke, \n                                            A. Godynyuk, \n                                            G. Wesley", 
    "D. Ciccarelli, \n                                            M. Lemieux, \n                                            J. Cullen", 
    "D. Rhodes, \n                                            S. Koivu, \n                                            W. Redden", 
    "M. Brodeur, \n                                            S. Thomas, \n                                            S. Niedermayer", 
    "J. Vanbiesbrouck, \n                                            S. Mellanby, \n                                            R. Brind'Amour", 
    "C. Chelios, \n                                            D. Savard, \n                                            R. Zednik", 
    "F. Potvin, \n                                            K. Muller, \n                                            J. Kurri", 
    "A. Moog, \n                                            C. Ludwig, \n                                            J. Nieuwendyk", 
    "A. Mogilny, \n                                            K. McLean, \n                                            J. Iginla", 
    "B. Nicholls, \n                                            J. Friesen, \n                                            D. Kasparaitis"
    ), c("Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER", 
    "Recap\n                                        \n                                \n                                        \n                                            GAMECENTER"
    ), c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Matchup\n                                    Matchup", 
"Result\n                                    Result", "", "Three Stars of the Game\n                            Three Stars of the Game", 
"", ""), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L)))
```

Comment: Clean up the names: `mydata %>% 
    map(repair_names) %>% 
    map_dfr(set_names, ~gsub('\\s+.*', '', .x), .id = 'element') %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, trimws)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your data frames in the `mydata` have duplicated column names, which could be a problem for `mutate_all`. Below I rename the data frames with letters from a to f, and then apply `mutate_all` and `str_squish` with `function(x)` to avoid any confusion. It seems working.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  map(set_names, letters[1:6]) %>%
  map(function(x) mutate_all(x, funs(str_squish(.))))
```

Therefore, when you create `mydata` you should avoid having duplicated column names.